# How to fix hover on element?

Tags: html, css

As you can see, If you run the code and you hover on the container, I't wont fully open, In other words the width of the container wont be fully expressed,i've tried removing the content paragraph max-width but that dosent seem to be the case, whenever i hover close to where the text supposed to be, It stopped midway.
Please i want the hover to transition fully no matter where i hover on the container div.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in;
  transition-delay: 250ms;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container:hover {
  width: 40%;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.circle::before {
  cursor: pointer;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: circle(30.3% at 50% 50%);
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in;
}

.circle:hover::before {
  clip-path: circle(70.7% at 50% 50%);
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.circle h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: 250ms ease;
  transition-delay: 250ms;
}

.container:hover .circle h1 {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition-delay: 250ms;
}

.content {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 250ms all ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.container:hover .content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: .5s;
  visibility: visible;
}

.content p {
  max-width: 300px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="circle">
      <h1>COCACOLA</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>COCACOLA</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam aperiam beatae amet, recusandae consectetur ut, officia nulla voluptatibus iure nobis vero ducimus. Corporis quidem tempora alias excepturi labore maxime ad?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please state your issue?

Comment: @ethry The container doesn't stay in it's hover state if you hover over anything other than the container itself. So the content, h1, etc.